# Auto copy and paste utility for Mac and Vim

Tags: osx, vim, clipboard

I would like to make a lot of copy- paste- text from my browser into `vim`. I'd like to streamline this process. I'm thinking of a utility that can do the following tasks:

1. When a text is highlighted, it should be copied automatically into the memory. There is already a utility that can do this:

   https://github.com/lodestone/macpaste
2. When a copy event occurs, I'd like the utility to, automatically, paste this event into a vim file running on `iTerm` (inside of `tmux`, if necessary) regardless where the cursor is located.

If a utility that can do these tasks is not available, which application do I need to write such a utility? Can this be done with higher level applications such as `Automator` or just `C` level applications can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Vim instance has access to the system clipboard (register `+`) or X selection (register `*`), you can use my [CaptureClipboard plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3246) for the second part. With `:CaptureClipboard`, the plugin monitors the clipboard for changes and inserts any change of clipboard contents into the current buffer.